# Problemas con mPDF

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un problema con mPDF en mi servidor. gracias por su ayuda.

Error - mPDF requires mb_string functions. Ensure that PHP is compiled with php_mbstring.dll enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema es que no esta habilitada la extensión de php mbstring.

Revisa el php.ini y en la seccion de extensión descomenta **extension=mbstring.so** o **extension=mbstring.dll** si es window para descomentar elimina el **;**

si usas xamp puedes hablitar la extensión gráficamente

verifica como habitar la extensión en tu Sistema Operativo.

Comment: hice eso pero no funciona..

Comment: Disculpa olvide comentar que debes reiniciar el apache